# How to set my application as the default downloader for specific extension

Tags: android

I'm using the code below to set my application as the default application to open my custom extension, it works fine.

Here's the thing, the file with my custom extension is sharable, and when a user share it via (Facebook Messenger for example), the user first clicks on the link, which open the default browser that offers the user to download the file, and later the user click on the downloaded file to get opened by my application.

**What I want is to get my application recognized as the downloader of this type of file to save the user the hussel of all the steps above.**

Thank you

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `android:scheme="file"`. This implies it is a local file.

If you're sharing a link to download the file, that link most certainly does not start with `file://`. Register a second `<data>` block that uses `android:scheme="https"` (and/or `http` as a third).

Comment: The application doesn't share a link, it shares the file itself, but technically what is being shared is a link to the file on Facebook server in case of the file being shared via messenger, I'll try your suggestion right away.

Comment: For sorry It didn't work, still it shows me a dialog (Cancel - Download) and when I select download it opens the default browser to start downloading it.

Comment: I tried with both http & https when I receive a file with my custom extension via Facebook Messenger, any more suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Ah, if you're just sending a files through Facebook Messenger, then they only offer downloading and it has to be a two step process.

Comment: You mean this process is set by Facebook messenger itself to open the browser to download the file?

Comment: OK, a work around, is it at least possible to set an intent filter to get my application notified when a file get downloaded with my own custom extension?